# Can Proguard obfuscate javascript code wrapped in Android App Code?

Tags: javascript, android, obfuscation

Can Proguard obfuscate javascript code wrapped in Android application? If not please suggest me some tools that allow to automate the javascript obfuscation process and integrate it a build tool.

Thank you for your time.

Regards,
Praveen.

Answer (score 1):

Proguard does not obfuscate JavaScript, it obfuscates bytecode (which is normally generated from Java code).

A simple Google search will lead you to many methods of obfuscating JavaScript.

Comment: But what if i use javascript in my web based Android application?  can i obfuscate it by a simple javascript obfuscator?

Comment: I cannot think of a reason why you wouldn't be able to. Obfuscated JS is not encrypted in any way, it's just made difficult for humans to read. The interpreter doesn't care if your variable and function names look like "password" or "a", it can still do its job.